# Python vectorization of matrix-vector operation

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, tensordot

I have a Matrix A with shape (2,2,N) and a Matrix V with shape (2,N)

I want to vectorize the following:

```
F = np.zeros(N)
for k in xrange(N):
    F[k] = np.dot( A[:,:,k], V[:,k] ).sum()
```

Any way this can be done with either tensordot or any other numpy function without explicit looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
F = np.einsum('ijk,jk->k',A,V)
```

We can optimize it further with `optimize` flag (check docs) set as `True`.